# Nose or pytest drop in to interactive console when running tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, console

When running nosetests I would like to drop in to an interactive console. However if I put the following anywhere in my code:

```
import code
code.interact(local=locals())
```

Nose just prints (InteractiveConsole) and does not provides the console to type in commands. Pytest treats code.interact as a failure. Is there a way I can drop into the console when running tests while also watching files for changes?

Comment: Have you tried using `pdb.set_trace()` and running pytest with the `-s` flag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to get an interactive session under pytest is to set a breakpoint with

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

Normally, pytest will supress this interactive session and will just hang when it hits the breakpoint. You can get around that by running pytest with the `-s` flag, which disables command line output capturing.

In the newest version of pytest, you can just use `pytest.set_trace()` without the `-s` flag to get the same behavior. See [the docs](http://pytest.org/latest/usage.html#setting-a-breakpoint-aka-set-trace) for info.